# Is there a way to keep local and remote files in sync?(local and remote machines are both ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, scp

I'm wondering how to keep a file in remote machine up to date with the same file in my local machine. More specifically, I have ubuntu 18.04 on both machines and I want to use local machine to edit some source files(that are on remote machine too) and then run it(remotely) on ssh. So it would be convenient if my local changes took effect immediately on the remote machine too.

When I used windows instead for local, there was precisely this feature in winScp. ([it is introduced here](https://www2.vrdc.cornell.edu/news/ecco/step-3-getting-your-data-on-and-off-ecco/using-winscp-to-transfer-and-synchronize-data-and-programs/)) But I can't find a way to do so in ubuntu no matter how hard I google it. Can you guys help me out here?

Comment: Can't you just use a version control system like Git? You can setup a private repo on https://github.com, setup git on both machines and voila! Whenever you make changes to the file you then push them to the repo. Whenever you switch to the other machine, you first pull latest changes and then start exploring

Comment: @festiv well, I agree that it would be a fair compromise but it takes not little effort to push and pull everytime I make minor changes. Not to mention that commits would be too many so I would have to make seperate branches to keep track of real important commits. So I asked because I'd like my files to be synchronized automatically.

Comment: I would suggest to use rsync instead of scp, https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync